# Value of type 'String' has no member 'substringToIndex' not resolved

Tags: ios, string, swift3

I am trying to grab currentLanguage of a device using the below function. But there has been an issue with substring and I don't seem to understand as previous answers have such simple solution of importing Foundation to the file, which didn't work for me.

```
class func currentLanguage() -> String
{
    let str = "en-US"       
    if let indexOfDash = str.characters.index(of: "-")
    {
        let langCode = str.substringToIndex(indexOfDash)

        return langCode
    }
}
```

In addition, What can be the best approach to get current language?

Comment: `substringToIndex` is Swift < 3.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
let langCode = str.substring(to: indexOfDash)
```

And you can get current language like that:

```
let pre = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

Comment: This seems to work mate! Haven't built as I have other issues to solve, will accept it answer as soon as I build it! :)